# How to create content for an e-commerce website which has a lot of expiring content?

Tags: seo, keywords, content

I am working on an [e-commerce](https://www.shopless.co.nz) website. Our website is similar Ebay. Users can list ad and advertise their products. For example, an employer who is **looking for a SQL developer**, would create a job listing on out website... this job would be listed for let's say 30 days and then removed.

We have thousands of jobs, cars, homes, etc listed on our website... and these listings keep getting posted and removed.

When we talk about the content of a website, are these ads considered our content? For example, the job advertisement related to the **SQL developer** would have relevant keywords and content... but this ad will expire in 30 days... and the link to this ad would disappear. Does these types of expiring content help us with SEO? Or do we need to create a blog and talk about relevant topics such as Recruitment, Online Trade, etc... obviously our blog content does not expire.

Now assuming I create a blog and include articles giving advice on finding a job and how to do job interview... advice about buying a car, etc... I would include some relevant keywords in these articles...

Let's say I would include the keyword "finding a job in New Zealand" in my blog about job... does it mean that someone searching the phrase "finding a job in New Zealand" would see my blog? But that's not what I want... I want the person to our job category when actually contains our job listings... not our blog.